# Modifying resultant table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2008

This is the resulting table

```
ItemCode   ItemName            Branch     Total Weight
------------------------------------------------------
FBV0001    SML WATER ARWA      Bayan         144.00 
FDR0014    RED LENTIL          Al Balad     3000.00 
FDR0014    RED LENTIL          Solidere    13500.00 
FDR0017    EGYPTIAN RICE       Solidere    75500.00
```

How to modify the resultant as below

```
ItemCode   ItemName            Bayan     Al Balad    Solidere
--------------------------------------------------------------
FBV0001    SML WATER ARWA      144.00        0            0 
FDR0014    RED LENTIL            0        3000.00         0 
FDR0014    RED LENTIL            0           0        13500.00 
FDR0017    EGYPTIAN RICE         0           0        75500.00
```

I have tried lot to queries but it is not working. Please give an idea how to obtain this.

Comment: You probably want [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx). Is the set of branches fixed?

Comment: yes, set of branches are fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Pivot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator. Something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ItemCode) AS RN
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT 
  ItemCode,
  ItemName,
  [Bayan], [Al Balad], [Solidere]
fROM CTE AS t
PIVOT
(
  MAX(TotalWeight)
  FOR Branch IN ([Bayan], [Al Balad], [Solidere])
) AS p;
```

**Note that:** I used the `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate a unique id to use to group by it. IF you didn't use a `ROW_NUMBER()`, you will get only one row from the two:

```
FDR0014      RED LENTIL
FDR0014      RED LENTIL
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84495/4).

This will give you:

```
| ITEMCODE |       ITEMNAME |  BAYAN | AL BALAD | SOLIDERE |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  FBV0001 | SML WATER ARWA |    144 |   (null) |   (null) |
|  FDR0014 |     RED LENTIL | (null) |     3000 |   (null) |
|  FDR0014 |     RED LENTIL | (null) |   (null) |    13500 |
|  FDR0017 |  EGYPTIAN RICE | (null) |   (null) |    75500 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the immediate response. It's working like a charm. Thanks a lot. superb. I will enchance my knowledge on pivot table

Comment: Yep, I checked. Very well guided. I really appreciate mahmoud gamal

Answer (score 0):

try this..here [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84495/8)

```
Select [itemcode],[itemname],
(Case when [branch]='Bayan' then [totalweight] else 0 end) as Bayan,
(Case when [branch]='AL BALAD' then [totalweight] else 0 end) as AL_BALAD,
(Case when [branch]='SOLIDERE' then [totalweight] else 0 end) as SOLIDERE
from Tablename
```

THE Output is like this..

```
ItemCode         ItemName                   Bayan     Al Balad         Solidere
FBV0001        SML WATER ARWA               144          0               0 
FDR0014        RED LENTIL                    0        3000               0 
FDR0014        RED LENTIL                    0            0              13500
FDR0017        EGYPTIAN RICE                 0            0              75500
```

Comment: Hi Amit singh this is also working fine. Thank you very much for your support